Unable to connect to Eduroam Network after updating Ubuntu to 24.04
Before the update the connection to eduroam worked flawlessly on Ubuntu 22.04. The connection to my home WI-FI as well as to a hotspot provided by my phone still works.
When trying to connect to eduroam for the first time after the update, I got:
NetworkManager[1063]: <info>  [1728396200.9546] audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=2455 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Failed to determine AP security information"

Trying to fix the issue by sticking to the steps indicated in this question Can't connect to Eduroam with Ubuntu 24.04 didn't work for me.

I checked the network configurations but they're correct: WPA2-Enterprise, PEAP (version 0), MSCHAPv2. Further,it does not seem to be an openssl problem, as I don't get any errors related to it when I do journalctl, still:
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023


I Updated /etc/default/grub by adding "ipv6.disable=1":
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"


After saving and rebooting:
sudo update-grub sudo reboot
sudo nmcli device wifi connect eduroam

I get:
NetworkManager[1147]: 
<info>  [1728473689.3678] 
audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=2444 uid=1000 result="fail"  
reason="Failed to determine AP security information"


I have these files:
ca.pem 
cat_installer.conf

After adding ca-certificate manually:
sudo cp /home/.../.cat_installer/ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates

I get:
NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1728474831.5589] 
audit: op="connection-add-activate" pid=14260 uid=1000 result="fail"  
reason="802.1x connections must have IWD provisioning files"



